# How do I know a task's start time of Task Scheduler through Windows API?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-task-scheduler

[image]

I want to know this start time in code.
I found this Mircosoft document about [ITask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Mstask/nn-mstask-itask).
It provides some methods to get the task's information such as application name, max run time and working directory ... but doesn't have what I need - start time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task start time is associated with the task trigger, not the task itself.
In the following code you need to initialize `IRegisteredTask` with the task that you are looking for.

Notice that a task may have more than one trigger and each could have a different type.

```
void GetStartTime(IRegisteredTask* pTask)
{
    ITaskTrigger *pTT = NULL;
    TASK_TRIGGER Trigger;   
    ITaskDefinition *pDefinition = NULL;
    ITriggerCollection *pTriggers = NULL;   
    pTask->get_Definition(&pDefinition);
    pDefinition->get_Triggers(&pTriggers);
    LONG cTriggers = 0;
    pTriggers->get_Count(&cTriggers);
    while (cTriggers > 0)
    {
        ITrigger *pT = NULL;
        pTriggers->get_Item(cTriggers, &pT);
        cTriggers--;
        BSTR bStart;
        pT->get_StartBoundary(&bStart);
        /*
        bStart will be some thing like L"2013-08-01T12:05:00"
        */
        ::SysFreeString(bStart);
        pT->Release();
    }
    pTriggers->Release();

}
```

Comment: You are missing `Release()` calls for the interfaces.

Comment: When I called pDefinition->get_Triggers(&pTriggers);, it crashed.Exception thrown: read access violation

Comment: Mostly the pDefination is not initialized on your environment. You need complete my code with check for the return values of the scheduler API before using it. my code is demonstration only.

Comment: @AhmedBahtity, I copied your code, and did the check. But it just failed. I don't know why. Then I tried another example, it worked.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/taskschd/c-c-code-example-retrieving-trigger-strings
Anyway, thank you gave me an important clue.

Comment: @AhmedBahtity, Finally, I know why. pTriggers->get_Item(cTriggers, &pT); The start index is 1, not 0. So, the cTriggers-- must be put behind.

Comment: @马化腾, You are correct. They state it in the docs.
I updated the answer.